# Wildcard search and replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, search, replacement

I have many documents consisting of text where words hav become incorrectly hyphenated. Like;

be-come; mons-ter; any-thing etc

I can search for the place where this has happened using;

\l-\l

any lowercase character and any other lowercaser character with a '-' in between.

How do I code the replacement to just remove the '-' character ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: looks like Scribus (DTP Software open source) has a dehyphenation feature: (search this doc for `deyhphenate`) https://fossies.org/linux/scribus/scribus/doc/en/hyphenator.html Scribus is scriptable I think.

Comment: Hi Scribus, thanks for the input, will be checking that out.

Comment: If any answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.

Comment: @Yorik When I paste text into Scribus and press dehyhphenate nothing happens. It looks like Scribus can only dehyphenate text that it has itself hyphenated, so basically something like an undo function. I haven't looked at the implementation though.

Comment: I guess it is looking for a "soft hyphen" and treats typed hyphens as inviolate

Answer (score 1):

Find what: `(\l)-(\l)`
Replace with: `$1$2`

[image]

Comment: ZygD - thanks so much for that answer. Of course, I have a follow up. What might I be able to do about the following; two-eyes-and-a-mouth where I don't want to make the change. I suppose what I am asking is how do I limit the replace to words which contain only a single '-' character ? Thanks again for such a fastr answer, appreciated.

Comment: Minor note: you won't really solve your problem by limiting to only a single hyphen, though you will limit the potential damage. The hyphenation you are attempting to remove is defined by syllable breaks, which really requires some sort of dictionary cross-reference (typographic software normally will use a hyphenation dictionary to find the breakpoints)

Comment: I believe the OP will not do "Replace All". I assume he will manually "Replace" after inspecting every occurrence.

Comment: Hi ZygD, after testing and using I think your right, I will have to do a one by one inspect and change. I actually think I have to more tightly frame my problem so I can automate it more. Thanks for the input and taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!-)\b(\l+)-(\l+)\b(?!-)`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!-)      # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't an hyphen before
\b          # word boundary
(\l+)       # group 1, 1 or more small letters
-           # an hyphen
(\l+)       # group 2, 1 or more small letters
\b          # word boundary
(?!-)       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't an hyphen after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Hi Toto, thanks so much for looking and the answer you posted. I have added a comment with a question below. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ramses505: see my edit.

Comment: HeyToto, thanks for taking the time to help out, appreciated.

Comment: @Ramses505: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)